# .properties file in java

Tags: java

I saw a lot of .properties files in java project. Is this kind of java standard files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Yes

You could have Googled. See here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties

See here

- JavaDoc http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html
- Real's How-to http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0434.html
- A tutorial (sorry, couldn't find a better one) http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util/Props.html